# Mark the Mark Scheme

Tags: c

I have successfully completed an AQA Computing exam (June 2011) in Delphi. Out of curiosity, I read the mark scheme for it. One thing I can't get over is that the C language mark scheme seems to be wrong on many aspects. Luckily (ha!) I did it in Delphi.

For example, this small snippet:

```
char* Names[5];
...
void main(void)
{
    Names[1] = "Ben";
    Names[2] = "Thor";
    Names[3] = "Zoe";
    Names[4] = "Kate";
    ...
}
```

For one, it's not possible to assign strings to an array. A function like strcpy must be used. Also, why do the arrays start at 1, even though 5 entries have been allocated? Most programming languages, including C, start at 0.

There are other problems, for example they use `printf("%s", "message");` to print strings; puts would be fine. And if you can be certain no unescaped percent signs would show up in the message, so would printf alone, with no arguments.

Am I right in my criticism of this?

Note: For those unfamiliar with mark schemes, they are what is used to mark the exams. I am questioning whether it is correct.

Comment: What make you think main() returns void?

Comment: @wildplasser: No idea - that's what is in the mark scheme.

Comment: I don't know what the Mark scheme is. What was your question?

Comment: @wildplasser The mark scheme is what is used to mark the exams. I'm questioning whether the mark scheme is correct here.

Comment: @Thomas So, if you did the exam in C and started the indexing at 0, would you get a bad grade?

Comment: Having a `void` main is valid, but might even give a warning. Most compilers will happily accept it though. As for the use of assigning string like in the example, I think you might need to look into how strings work in C a little more.

Comment: @Joachim: C99 §5.1.2.2.1: "[main] shall be defined with a return type of *int*...or in some other implementation-defined manner." Implementations that accept `void main` aren't breaking with the standard, but `void main` is decidedly not part of the C standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting the index at 1 is weird, and main doesn't return void in C, but the array assignment is valid. `Names` is an array of pointers, and "Ben" looks like a string pointer. You would need to to use `strcpy` only if you wanted to copy the strings into space allocated for them. That program will still compile if the compiler isn't too picky and it doesn't have runtime issues unless someone refers to `Names[5]`.

The printf thing is actually better. `puts` is bad juju and, as you pointed out, you can't be certain that no unescaped `%`s appear in the string.

Comment: Would problems occur then if an attempt were made to modify the string in the array?

Comment: @ThomasO: Yes, they would. Those strings are probably allocated in read only memory with the rest of the constants (I don't remember if the standard guarantees that) so bad things can happen if someone says `Names[3][2] = 'F'`.

Answer (score 1):

> For one, it's not possible to assign strings to an array.

This statement is by an large correct. However this is not what's going on in the code. What happens there is a pointer assignment. You can assign an address of a string, which is a pointer, to another pointer, which happens to be an element of an array.

> why do the arrays start at 1

Perhaps the code is translated from another language (BASIC?). Maybe the goal here is as close a translation as possible, so that solutions in different languages can be easily compared.

Answer (score 0):

In fact your understanding is wrong in this case.

The Names array is defined as being an array of char pointers.
"Ben", "Thor" etc. are all char pointers and as such can legitamtely be assigned to any of the Names array entries.

Yes the first element is at the 0 index, but they may not be wishing to code to that. Perhaps they are going to ask what value the first element would have - in this case it would be uninitilised and therefore of undefined value depending on the compiler.

Also the printf statement is a safer command than puts and allows for some type checking on use.